# how can i show datagrid inside tooltip .. not tooltip for datagrid!

Tags: wpf, binding, tooltip, listboxitem

I have a listbox and its bound.  and i have tooltip on listbox item sometihng like this

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
      <!--<EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="ListBox_MouseEnter" />-->
      <!--<EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="ListBox_MouseLeave" />-->
      <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{StaticResource mytooltip}"></Setter>
   </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Now i want to show a datagrid inside tooltip which databound ....

Any ideas please???

thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
<ListBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataSource}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource listBoxTemplate}">
</ListBox>


<DataTemplate x:Key="listBoxTemplate">            
    <WrapPanel>
        <Image
            Stretch="None"
            Source="/LearningSuite;component/Resources/Images/check.png" />
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/> 
            <TextBlock> 
                <Hyperlink
                    NavigateUri="http://google.com"
                    RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"></TextBlock>
                </Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
        </TextBlock>
        <WrapPanel.ToolTip>
            <Grid>
                [Your code will go here]
            </Grid>
        </WrapPanel.ToolTip>
    </WrapPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a custom template for the tool tip.  Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745107.aspx) out.